# Calculating Average Cost per day to Travel to a City

Tags: average

I have a list of travelers, their total cost to travel per trip, and number of days traveled for each trip.

Is this formula correct for the average cost per day to travel?

Traveler's Total Trip Cost / Number of Travel Days = Cost per day

Cost per day Total (of all People) / Total Number of Trips = Average Cost per day

$7841.78/24 = **$326.74**

---

WHY DO I GET A DIFFERENT NUMBER USING THIS FORMULA-

Total Travel Cost (all people) / Number of Trips = Average Cost per trip

$34736.46/24 = $1447.35

Number of Travel Days / Number of Trips = Average Number of days per trip
108/24 = 4.5

Average Cost per Trip / Average Number of Days per Trip = Average Cost per day
$1447.35/4.5 = **$321.63**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your cost per day in the first part is not correct. If the total travel cost is $34736.46$, then the cost per day is $7719.21$ not $7841.78$

Comment: I'm thinking too much, I can use: Total Cost of all trips/Number of days traveled=Cost per day